# Receiving the error "Struct() argument 1 must be string, not unicode" when using Django

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am receiving the error "Struct() argument 1 must be string, not unicode" when running a script in Django but it runs OK in python.
I'm trying to translate the hex version of a SID from Active Directory to the string version.
The error says argument 1 is unicode but from what I can tell it's not.
From what I can tell argument 1 is the sliced value of SID.

Any help is appreciated. 
        Here is the code:

```
        result = con.search_s(ldap_base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, criteria, 
        attributes)

        sid = result[0][1]["objectSid"][0]

        if sys.version_info.major < 3:
            revision = ord(sid[0])
        else:
            revision = sid[0]

        if sys.version_info.major < 3:
            number_of_sub_ids = ord(sid[1])
        else:
            number_of_sub_ids = sid[1]

        iav = struct.unpack('>Q', b'\x00\x00' + sid[2:8])[0]

        sub_ids = [struct.unpack('<I', sid[8 + 4 * i:12 + 4 * i])[0]
                    for i in range(number_of_sub_ids)]

        sid = 'S-{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(revision, iav, '-'.join([str(sub_id) 
        for sub_id in sub_ids]))
```

Error part 1-
[image]

Error part 2-
[image]

Error part 3-
[image]

Comment: Please post text, not images.  In any case, I can't reproduce the problem.  I suspected a `from __future__ import unicode_literals` was used above this code, but it didn't cause the error.  `struct.unpack` didn't care if its first parameter was Unicode or not.  Make a small, **completely** reproducible example that can be cut-and-pasted and tested.  You'll probably figure out the problem by trying to do that anyway.

Comment: Thanks for looking. It does work OK when I run the code separately in python itself. I did see this mentioned on other posts but the views.py file doesn't include any reference to "from __future__ import unicode_literals".